# No test output from mocha-phantomjs

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocha-phantomjs

I'm having trouble getting the simplest mocha-phantomjs test to work on Windows, from the command-line. It seems to run the javascript - as I can see some output from `console.log`, but I'm not seeing any test output.

I did `npm install` on the following packages

- mocha-phantomjs (4.0.2)
- phantomjs (2.1.3)
- mocha (2.4.4)
- chai (3.5.0)

**test\cow-test.js**:

```
console.log("fred1");

describe("OnePlusFour", function() {
  it("should be able to add two numbers", function() {
    chai = require('chai');
    var expect = chai.expect;

    var first = 1;
    var second = 4;
    expect(first + second).to.equal(5);
  });
});

console.log("fred2");
```

**cow.html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Cow tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="./node_modules/mocha/mocha.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="mocha"></div>

  <script src="./node_modules/mocha/mocha.js"></script>
  <script src="./node_modules/chai/chai.js"></script>

  <script>
    mocha.setup('bdd');
  </script>

  <script src="test/cow-test.js"></script>

  <script>
      mocha.run();
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run mocha on the javascript file, I get the correct test output:

```
D:\Sandbox\GummyBear>mocha test\cow-test.js
fred1
fred2


  OnePlusFour
    √ should be able to add two numbers


  1 passing (10ms)
```

Yay! But when I run mocha-phantomjs on the HTML file, I only get console output and nothing from the test:

```
D:\Sandbox\GummyBear>mocha-phantomjs cow.html
fred1
fred2

^CTerminate batch job (Y/N)? y
```

and I have to use Ctrl+Break to terminate it, or it will stay there forever. Boo.

What am I doing wrong?

BTW eventually I want to get this working with gulp. I used the MVC Boilerplate templates to create a project structure with ASP.NET Core, bower and gulp etc, but I got stuck at the javascript unit test stage (gulp-mocha-phantomjs gave the error "mocha was not found in the page within 10000ms of the page loading."). So in order to solve that, I wanted to get my head around the basics of JS unit testing first.

Comment: Did you try just opening the html file in a browser?

Comment: Yeah, that worked fine.

Comment: For completeness I should say that I have now switched from the above setup to: gulp-mocha, request, zombie, chai and cheerio. As mentioned here: https://tanzimsaqib.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/continuous-functional-test-automation-with-gulp-mocha-request-cheerio-chai/

Comment: have you tried moving the expect declaration into the html file?  Not sure why that would help.  but I declare mine in the html file after the bdd,        mocha.ui('bdd');
expect = chai.expect;

Comment: I just tried that, it didn't make any difference.

Comment: let me know if you figure it out, I am kind of having a similar problem, but with mocha-phantomjs-core